# Will I need to be PCI Compliant if using Commerce Authorize.Net module as payment method

Tags: drupal-commerce

If I use the [Commerce Authorize.Net](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_authnet) module and use Authorize.net as the payment method, will I have to be PCI compliant?  Was hoping that during payment it is an Iframe from authorize.net and I won't need to be PCI compliant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an iframe or sending to Authorize.net page you will need to be SAQ-A PCI Compliant.